# Как сделать проверку введенного кода javascript на сайте?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать проверку введенного кода javascript на сайте? Пример с сайта http://www.codewars.com/

Суть в том что человек в окошко вводит код и мне надо его проверить при нажатии на кнопку, а потом получить результат верно ли введен код))

Я уже пробовал jasmine и qUnit - тесты удавалось проводить, но я все никак не пойму как мне взять код с окна в которое вводят код и проверить его, а потом понять верно ли введен код в окне, а уже от этого вывести правильно решена задача или нет.
[image: codewars]

Comment: выполняйте тесты на сервере.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Попробую